# Spark reads all columns in filtering when using scala syntax

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, catalyst-optimizer, frameless

This code is good, it only reads the column `i` (notice the last line `ReadSchema: struct<i:bigint>`, which only reads `i`):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

// Define the case class
case class Foo(i: Long, j: String)

// Create a Dataset of Foo
val ds: Dataset[Foo] = spark.createDataset(Seq(
  Foo(1, "Q"),
  Foo(10, "W"),
  Foo(100, "E")
))

// Filter and cast the column
val result = ds.filter($"i" === 2).select($"i")

// Explain the query plan
result.explain()

// It prints:
//== Physical Plan ==
//*(1) Filter (isnotnull(i#225L) AND (i#225L = 2))
//+- *(1) ColumnarToRow
//   +- FileScan parquet [i#225L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(i#225L), (i#225L = 2)], //Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[dbfs:/tmp/foo], PartitionFilters: [], //PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(i), EqualTo(i,2)], ReadSchema: struct<i:bigint>
```

However, if i use `val result = ds.filter(_.i == 10).map(_.i)`, the physical plan will read all columns including `j` (notice the last line `ReadSchema: struct<i:bigint,j:string>`):

```
//= Physical Plan ==
//*(1) SerializeFromObject [input[0, bigint, false] AS value#336L]
//+- *(1) MapElements //$line64a700cfcea442ea899a5731e37978a9115.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$Lambda$8811/2079//839768@1028cff, obj#335: bigint
//   +- *(1) Filter //$line64a700cfcea442ea899a5731e37978a9115.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$Lambda$8810/7014//15521@212ee011.apply
//      +- *(1) DeserializeToObject newInstance(class //$line64a700cfcea442ea899a5731e37978a925.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Foo), obj#334: //$line64a700cfcea442ea899a5731e37978a925.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Foo
//         +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
//            +- FileScan parquet [i#225L,j#226] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, //Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[dbfs:/tmp/foo], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], //ReadSchema: struct<i:bigint,j:string>
```

Why does spark handle differently when i use the scala syntax `_.i` inside filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_ forces collection, tuple processing like rdd due to scala `map`. You see `ColumnarToRow` & `DeserilaizeToObject` in physical plan.

Catalyst has little insight into Scala code and this is an old aspect if you google. `ds.map(_.x)` is same as `col("x")` but Spark Catalyst still does nothing in this regard.

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14083. Note that they are aware of this but it has not been catered for.

Comment: May I know why `_` forces collection?

Comment: It is just part of Scala. I did not invent it. You get rdd type processing mixed with df.

Comment: The thing is if i use ds.filter($"i" === 2).select($"i"), it's not type safe, right? This loses the type safety feature of Dataset.

Comment: if you are concerned about this, use [frameless](https://github.com/typelevel/frameless/) it will work with the column api behind the scenes but provides compile time safety.  It also comes with many other goodies like custom Encoder derivation.  Although it's type safe it would still allow push down optimisations etc.

Comment: Different question path.

Answer (score 1):

Dataframe API (using column references) and Dataset API are different not only in the way to describe the plan but also in the way that is managed.

Dataset transformations are created with lambdas and are like UDFs to the spark optimizer because it can't see what's happening underneath. If you really want Spark to optimize your query it's recommended to use only dataframe API.

Comment: It's not the dataframe api that you "only use", sql via strings (in filter, selectExpr and expr) are all compiled to the same underlying Expressions.
From a performance standpoint that black box costs - note the PushedFilters section in the plan.  In the first example using the api EqualTo(i,2) is present, in the second there are no pushed down filters.  Without pushedfilters spark must load all the records into memory and cannot use file or database level information to reduce work

Comment: Could you give examples where dataframe outperforms dataset, and maybe explain a bit? (usually dataframe is just Dataset[Row] no?)

Comment: This could be a further question, but, in short, sql / column api etc. is pure spark expressions, underlying it all are "InternalRow"'s, any time they need to be converted into a user class (and back again, in both cases via Encoders) it has additional cost (in some cases several times slower).  As per Alfilercio's point Spark cannot know what you do in your own code, it cannot know to push down data, or that it can optimise a query based on the transformation.  Pure sql / column api does this.  Whilst you could take a "Row" in a filter, it too would suffer the costs.

Comment: @Chris, could all these drawbacks of dataset (additional costs due to user class) be avoided by frameless? or say, can we consider frameless as performant as dataframe?

Comment: only in that situation of using it as a better typed dataset (i.e. column names are type checked).  Nothing can avoid the costs of serializing the second you break out of the internal spark apis and functions.

Comment: @Chris Is the frameless you mentioned popularly used? Or say, is it considered the best option when writing production code? Is there drawback compared to Spark Dataset?

Comment: you should make decisions based on whether you would want to use it and if it will help you, trying it only costs your time.  The only real drawback is it requires a case class type in order to know which fields are possible at compile time.